# Is there a possibility in Maven to specify a "default" scope for a library - e.g. test for junit

Tags: maven

Projects like junit are 99% used in scope test. Compile is the default scope. Is it possible in maven as a maintainer of a library to specify the default scope of the library as "test"?

I did not find a way to specify that - so I guess every dependency has to explicitly be marked as test scope only - which makes the pom.xml where it is included easier to read.

Comment: Where should this list go and who would be responsible for it?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen In theory, your POM could define a `<defaultScope>` along the `artifactId` and `groupId`, but I do not think this would be terribly useful. Especially because many libraries are used in different scopes.

Comment: @JFabianMeier it is my understanding that OP want this to go outside his own project. So, where should it go and who decides what the default value should be? This rhetorical question should hopefully reveal that it is rather hard to design a generic solution.

Comment: What I wanted was that the junit team can say "this is most commonly used in test scope, so this is the default" or e.g. implementations of the Jarkata EE API say that they are should not be coded against -> runtime only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not as the maintainer of a libary.

Often it is helpful to define a so-called "BOM": A pom only project that lists dependencyManagement. It can be imported into other projects with `<scope>import</scope>`.

You can e.g. define a third-party-bom, including junit in scope test with a certain version. Then the user of the third-party-bom only need to specify groupId and artifactId.

Comment: Thank you :) I can understand that this is a very useful solution to my problem as I have to define this only once :)